# Image source from database cannot display the image on react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, file-upload, web-development-server

I'm using react and node using form data to upload files to mongo db. While retrieving them the source does not display the images.
Here is my code to retrieve info from images database

```
const [imagespath, setimagespath] = useState([])
useEffect(()=>{
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/getimages").then((response)=>{
    setimagespath(response.data)   
})
```

},[])

What couls I have possibly done wrong?

Here is the code to display the image

```
{imagespath.map((image)=>{
        return( 
        <div className='galleryItem'>
          <img src={image.filepath} alt="" />
        </div> )
      })}
```

Comment: Can you use a console.log(image) in the second line in your second code ?
And show us the out

Answer (score 0):

You try to map data before its fetched. You should use optional chaining:

```
{imagespath?.map((image)=>{
```

or conditional rendering:

```
{ imagespath ? imagespath.map((image)=>{
    return( 
    <div className='galleryItem'>
      <img src={image.filepath} alt="" />
    </div> )
  }) : 
'No image provided'
}
```